# How to change codeoffset?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, pic, bootloader, microchip

I know how to change the codeoffset on MPLAB XC8 easily just by going to `XC8 Linker --> Additional options -- > Codeoffset`

**How do I change it on MPLAB V8.92 with C18 compiler?** I am using PIC18F87J11 if that's helpful.  I opened the linker file and changed the following but it gave me error. I don't know if I am suppose to do that or not, but all I really want is to change the codeoffset so that the hex file starts at address 10000. I have a bootloader that occupies the following memory space 0-10000. I want the application code to start at address 10000. I can do this fine with MPLAB XC8 but I don't know how to do it with MPLAB 8. Most of my projects are written with MPLAB 8 so converting to MPLAB XC8 would take some time.

**Linker file changed from**

```
CODEPAGE NAME=page START=0x0 END=0x1FFF7
```

**To**

```
CODEPAGE NAME=page START=0x10000 END=0x1FFF7
```

Build Error:

```
Error - section '_entry_scn' can not fit the absolute section. Section '_entry_scn' start=0x00000000, length=0x00000006
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A majority of this information was taken from the [microchip forum](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m794609.aspx) and reproduced here for convenience.  There is also a lot of great information on how to utilize the linker in [Microchip's MPLINK Object Linker User's Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/33014L.pdf).

Copy the start up file c018i.c (or whatever you are using) from C18's startup directory to your project file and **add it to your project**.

Edit the line:

```
#pragma code _entry_scn=0x000000
```

to

```
#pragma code _entry_scn=0x010000
```

Next copy the linker file **18f87j11_g.lkr** to your project and add that to your project.
Edit the linker and comment out the default start up file so it will use the local copy:

```
#IFDEF _CRUNTIME
    #IFDEF _EXTENDEDMODE
        //FILES c018i_e.o
        FILES clib_e.lib
        FILES p18f87j11_e.lib

    #ELSE
        //FILES c018i.o
        FILES clib.lib
        FILES p18f87j11.lib
    #FI
```

If you are writing a bootloader, you will need to have a fixed place for the interrupt vectors so get the bootloader code to vector them to a fixed location and then add the following:

```
#pragma code highVector=0x10008
void HighVector(void) {
    _asm
    goto high_isr
    _endasm
}

#pragma code lowVector=0x10018
void LowVector(void) {
    _asm goto low_isr _endasm
}

#pragma code // Return to default code section
```

Then....

```
#pragma interrupt high_isr
void high_isr(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Finally, in the linker you also have to protect the bootloader memory area by adding this line:

```
CODEPAGE NAME=bootloader START=0x000000 END=0X00FFFF PROTECTED
```

And modifying the "page" to start the program where you want it, like so:

```
CODEPAGE NAME=page START=0x100000 END=0X01FFF7
```

I was able to get a simple program to compile and link using the above steps.  You can see in the image of my map file that the code is properly offset.

[image: Screenshot of map file]

Comment: Do I need to change the page start to the following? `CODEPAGE NAME=page START=0x10000 END=0x1FFF7`

Comment: I am still getting the same error `Error - section '_entry_scn' can not fit the absolute section. Section '_entry_scn' start=0x00100000, length=0x00000006' can not fit the absolute section.` I still need to to follow the links you posted, but hopefully they will lead me somewhere. Thanks though for putting everything together.

Comment: In answer to your first comment, I believe that you do.  I cannot verify right now though.  I'll take a look later and see if I can confirm.

Comment: @Ammar I updated specifically for your microcontroller and verified that a program will compile/link properly using the steps above.